# ggplot - How can I combine two scatter plots from different data.frames and use distinct colorset to identify each dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

```
# df1
x = c(3, 5, 8, 2)
y = c(5, 4, 7, 9)
gender = c(1, 0 ,0, 1)
df1 = data.frame(x, y, gender)
        
# df2
x = c(1, 6, 4, 8, 3, 6)
y = c(2, 7, 8, 0, 2, 1)
gender = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
df2 = data.frame(x, y, gender)
```

I wish create a single scatter plot (x, y) from both dataframe and color by gender, use different color to distinguish points from different dataframes.
For example - use red and light red for gender in df1 and use blue and light blue for gender in df2

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please try to complete your question by shown how you want to combine the data frames and then how you already plot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, for sure you can change the colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Plot 1
G1 <- ggplot(df1,aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(gender)))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','deeppink'))
#Plot 1
G2 <- ggplot(df2,aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(gender)))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','darkviolet'))
#Combine
G1+G2
```

[image]

**Update**

You can have all in one plot as you want using this:

```
#Code
df1$id <- 'df1'
df2$id <- 'df2'
df <- rbind(df1,df2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(interaction(id,gender))))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','deeppink','blue','darkviolet'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to create a single scatter plot with points from both dataframes.

Comment: I meant, is there a way to create a single scatter plot containing points from both dataframes. Points are colored by gender. But each dataframe has unique colorset for gender (for ex. blue, light blue for df1 and red, light red for df2)

Comment: @Siddhartha I have updated the solution. I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot! I was wondering if there is a way to write legends more neatly. I have an example picture in question.

Comment: @Siddhartha You can look for `guides()` in order to customize your leged. I don't see any picture in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @Siddhartha If you believe this answer was helpful in any way you could accept it or upvote it in the left side of this answer. Thank you!!!